# How to grouping item cart by shop_id using RecyclerView in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Okey, I have list item in Cart Activity (using RecyclerView). My purpose is to separate items based on **shop_id** so users can process payment once when there is an item that has the same shop_id. I have googled and I have read a solution using `getItemViewType`, but I have no idea because in my case, `shop_id` is dynamic.

This is the illustration:

```
item A
item F
(here button process item A and F)

item D
(here button process item D)

item B
item E
item C
(here button process item B,E and C)
```

Please help me, thanks!

Comment: Hi Drisoel , can you give some brief explanation?

Comment: You have list of items with diffrent shop id's and you need to filter list of diffrent shop ids and their items right?

Comment: I want to grouping when there are items that have the same shop ID

Comment: I have added my answer please check it.

Answer (score 1):

I am having an example for you.

```
    data class CartItem(
            var shopId : Int,
            var itemName : String
    )

    val list = listOf(CartItem(1,"Onion"),
            CartItem(1,"Potato"),
            CartItem(2,"Banana"),
            CartItem(2,"Apple"))

    val listOfDifferentShopIds = mutableListOf<List<CartItem>>()

    val getUniqueShopIds = list.distinctBy { it.shopId }.map { it.shopId }

    getUniqueShopIds.forEach{ uniqueShopID->
        listOfDifferentShopIds.add(list.filter{ uniqueShopID == it.shopId })
    }

    print(listOfDifferentShopIds)
```

**Result**

```
[[CartItem(shopId=1, itemName=Onion), CartItem(shopId=1, itemName=Potato)], [CartItem(shopId=2, itemName=Banana), CartItem(shopId=2, itemName=Apple)]]
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: I already try this solution, but in the UI how to group the items and separate it? Thanks anyway!

Comment: posting your code will help me to give you more clear answer

Comment: Hi Happy Singh, I've solved the problem by follow the example from github. But anyway, thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: @sirdn4 can u share me the github link?

Comment: Sure! https://github.com/manticarodrigo/kotlin-nested-recyclerviews